# i calculate a transition matrix ,but the sum of one row is small than 1. i want to know how to do with it?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

The problem is that :
 Given the following sequences of observations,estimate the parameters for the weather MC(s=sunny,c=cloudy,r = rainy):
c,c,r,c,r,c,s,s
s,c,r,r,r,s,c,c
s,s,s,c,r,r,r,c
r,r,c,r,c,s,s,s

I calculate the transition matrix is $$
 \left[
 \begin{matrix}
   \frac{6}{10}  & \frac{3}{10} & 0 \\
   \frac{3}{11} & \frac{2}{11} & \frac{6}{11} \\
   \frac{1}{11} & \frac{5}{11} & \frac{5}{11}
  \end{matrix}
  \right] \tag{3}
$$
and the sum of frist row is not equal to 1.I think a while and find the last state has none next state. I am a little confused what to do next.